# Include model comments from Simulink in generated code

Tags: simulink

Is there a way to add comment to Simulink in a way which will be later added to the generated code?

Rational, sometimes i look at the generated code and I would like to see my comments for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `Model-Wide Utilities` library there is a `DocBlock`.  If you select the Text option, then the comments can be included in code generated by Simulink Coder.